# CakePHP Missing Controller - but it exists

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, shared-hosting, cakephp-1.3

I recently downloaded cakephp-1.3.4. I set it up on my web server. I followed the advanced installation settings. My folder structure is as follows.

```
/common/
  cakephp/
     app/
     etc...
/htdoc/
```

The `/htdoc` folder is the webroot; `cakephp` resides in the `common` folder.

I have configured the paths in index.php to point to this folder structure. I have the app up and running. I created a layout, the app has picked it up (along with all the css and images - all that works).

I created a `posts_controller.php` in `cakephp/app/controllers/`. Now when I try to access the following page: http://localhost/posts. I get a message that the controller cannot be found and that I should create a `app/controllers/posts_controller.php` (it already exists!).

Also the strange thing is using the default pages_controller **works**. I created an about.ctp and dropped it in `app/views/pages/about.ctp`. Vising http://localhost/pages/about shows up as expected.

**SOLUTION:**

Sam helped me solve this problem (see the long comment thread below). The problem was I had set relative paths for my ROOT folder. This messed things up. The solution is to either directly set an **absolute path** or call `realpath` with your relative path for it to be resolved into the right absolute path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your controller class is named correctly (should be PostsController) and inherits from AppController (not strictly necessary but good practice).

Comment: @Sam: I copy pasted the code it shows on the Missing Controller page. So the name is PostsController and it does inherit from AppController

Comment: What are you using for hosting? Are your file permissions ok?

Comment: @Sam: This is a shared hosting server. I did not modify the file permissions, other than what cakePHP asked me to in the initial set up (like setting the `tmp` folder as writable etc.)

Comment: @aip.cd.aish: It just occurred to me that the pages_controller resides inside the core CakePHP installation. It sounds to me like CakePHP is having trouble accessing your /app directory at all. Double check you've configured it correctly and file permissions are ok.

Comment: @Sam: My layouts and view code which reside in the `app` folder got picked up correctly. Is there anything in specific I should check?

Comment: @aip.cd.aish: More specifically, make sure your ROOT and APP_DIR is set correctly in webroot/index.php, as per documentation here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/915/Advanced-Installation

Comment: Also, you could try putting a snippet of code at the bottom of webroot/index.php (before $Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();) as follows: `pr(App::path("controllers"));`

Comment: +1 @Sam: That helped some. Doing the above, I saw 3 different paths. The first one is where the posts_controller resides. The second one was just the app/ folder itself. I tried moving the posts_controller there and that works. But I don't think that is the best solution. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: @aip.cd.aish: Can you paste in the paths that are being shown?

Comment: @Sam: `[0]=>../common/cakephp-df6ffd4/app/controllers/
[1]=>../common/cakephp-df6ffd4/app/
[2]=>/f5/mysite/common/cakephp-df6ffd4/cake/libs/controller/
`

Comment: Okay your paths look a little messed up, make sure your ROOT is set to an absolute path, not a relative one. Use realpath() from webroot/index.php or something.

Comment: @Sam: You my friend are awesome! That was it, I passed the relative path to `realpath` and set that as the new path and it worked beautifully. I was the one who set the relative paths. Thanks! :)

Comment: I should have searched SO first! Would have saved me alot of time. I just paid the stupid tax.